# is it possible for middleware to add values to app when using SLIM

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, slim

I'm using slim to create a rest api and trying to use middleware to set up authentication / authorisation. Authenticate is working however I need to be able to access the users permissions outside of the middleware so I need some way to ether return the users permissions or just the user (and obtain their permissions later), alternatively a way to make sure that the same instance of slim is being used would also solve my issue. This is the first time I've used slim and middleware in a project and unsure how to do this, or if this is actually not possible and I should use a different method.

The middleware is as follows:

```
class TokenOverBasicAuth extends \Slim\Middleware
{
    protected $settings = array(
        'realm' => 'Protected Area',
        'root'  => '/'
    );

    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        if (!isset($this->app)) {
            $this->app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        }
        $this->config = array_merge($this->settings, $config);
    }

    public function call()
    {
        $req = $this->app->request();
        $res = $this->app->response();

        $authUser = $req->headers('PHP_AUTH_USER');
        $authToken = $req->headers('PHP_AUTH_PW');

        if (preg_match('|^/api/v.*$|', $req->getPath(), $req->getResourceUri()) && (!($authToken && $authUser && $this->verify($authUser, $authToken)))) {
            $res->status(401);
            $res->header(
               'WWW-Authenticate',
                sprintf('Basic realm="%s"', $this->config['realm'])
            );
            $res->body(json_encode(array("401" => '401 Unauthorized',
                                         "status" => '401')
                                         ));
        } else {
            $this->next->call();
        }
    }

    protected function verify($authUser, $authToken)
    {
        $user = // A call yo the database for user details based on token and password
        if (false !== $user && count($user) == 1) {

            $this->app->user = $user;
            if ( ! empty ($u->permission->access)) {
                $u->permission->access = unserialize($this->app->user->permission->access);
            }
            // calling print_r($this->app->user); here shows expected results
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'm calling the middleware in my bootstrap using:

```
$app->add(new API\Middleware\TokenOverBasicAuth(array('root' => '/api/v1')));
```

Trying to access the value of user e.g. `print_r($app->user);` directly after this shows that there isn’t anything recorded.

Please let me know if i need to explain anything more, this is my first time asking on here.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling print_r($app->user)? Have you tried calling it inside a route?

Comment: I've tried in a number on places including a route.

Currently I'm thinking of trying to make a separate method that checks auth that can be called both inside and outside the middle-ware so I can recover the user this way instead.